# unix sort multiple fields

Tags: unix, sorting, field

I'm trying to sort the file below as follows:

col1 (Ascending) col2 (Descending) col3 (Ascending) col4 (Descending)

I want to use the `-k` command, not the `+-` syntax.
I've figured out how to use the old syntax:

```
sort -t " " +0 -1 +2 -3 +4r testfile
```

but it's hardly intuitive.
I haven't figured out the right way to use the `-k` option. Thank you.

Here's the testfile:

```
5 3 2 9
3 4 1 7
5 2 3 1
6 1 3 6
1 2 4 5
3 1 2 3
5 2 2 3
```

Result:

```
1 2 4 5
3 4 1 7
3 1 2 3
5 3 2 9
5 2 2 3
5 2 3 1
6 1 3 6
```

Comment: Your "Result" data doesn't match the output of your old syntax example.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need one of:

```
sort --key=1,1 --key=2,2r --key=3,3 --key=4,4r
sort -k1,1 -k2,2r -k3,3 -k4,4r
```

as in the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo '5 3 2 9
3 4 1 7
5 2 3 1
6 1 3 6
1 2 4 5
3 1 2 3
5 2 2 3' | sort --key=1,1 --key=2,2r --key=3,3 --key=4,4r

1 2 4 5
3 4 1 7
3 1 2 3
5 3 2 9
5 2 2 3
5 2 3 1
6 1 3 6
```

Remember to provide the `-n` option if you want them treated as proper numbers (variable length), such as:

```
sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2r -k3,3 -k4,4r
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `sort -n -k 1n -k 2rn -k 3n -k 4rn`?
`-k <FIELD><OPT1><OPT2>...` where OPT1 and OPt2 are simply `sort` options, for example `n` is numeric, `r` is reverse